# http.put method on angular4

Tags: angular, api, promise

i try to connect my app to an Api using the promises.
the update method work's fine but the update one did't work. 
here it is :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()

export class Croissants {
    text: string;
    ownerId: number[];
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
}

export class Personnes {
    text: string;
    id: number;
    color: string;
}


export class EventService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getCroissants() {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/v0/croissants')
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(res => <any[]> res.json().data)
                    .then(data => { return data; });
    }

    updateCroissants(ownerId, startDate, endDate, text) {
        return this.http.put('http://localhost:8080/v0/croissant' + ownerId + startDate + endDate + text)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(res => <any[]> res.json().data)
                    .then(data => { return data; });
    }

    deleteCroissants(ownerId) {
        return this.http.delete('http://localhost:8080/v0/croissant' + ownerId)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(res => <any[]> res.json().data)
                    .then(data => { return data; });
    }

    getPersonnes() {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/v0/persons')
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(res => <any[]> res.json().data)
                    .then(data => { return data; });
    }

}
```

On the update it says : 
" Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target "

for further help i give the component :

```
import { NgModule, Component, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import {Croissants, Personnes, Service} from './calendrier.service';
import {DxSchedulerModule, DxCheckBoxModule, DxSelectBoxModule} from 'devextreme-angular';

if(!/localhost/.test(document.location.host)) {
    enableProdMode();
}

@Component({
    selector: 'calendrier',
    templateUrl: './calendrier.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./calendrier.component.css'],
    providers: [Service]
})
export class CalendrierComponent {
    CroissantsData: Croissants[];
    currentDate: Date = new Date(2015, 4, 25);
    PersonnesData: Personnes[];
    switchModeNames: string[];

    constructor(service: Service) {
        this.switchModeNames = ["Tabs", "Drop-Down Menu"];

        this.CroissantsData = service.getCroissants();
        this.PersonnesData = service.getPersonnes();
        console.log(this.CroissantsData);
    }
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        DxSchedulerModule,
        DxCheckBoxModule,
        DxSelectBoxModule
    ],
    declarations: [CalendrierComponent],
    bootstrap: [CalendrierComponent]
})
export class CalendrierModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(CalendrierModule)
```

all my code is available on my github if you want to keep an eye on it :

> https://github.com/MehdyDriouech/Croissantboard

Thanks very very much for help

Comment: `this.http.put('http://localhost:8080/v0/croissants+'id,'')` what is this? What should it look like if id is defined? Something like `http://localhost:8080/v0/croissants/1` ?

Comment: it's the id of the event i want to update. it's on an other component. Did i do right using this synthax ?
So yes, when it's defined it's look like exactly what your wrote

Comment: Then it should be like `return this.http.put('http://localhost:8080/v0/croissants/'+id)` but where do you provide the id?

Comment: The id came from another component

Comment: If you make the url like that it will give something like: `http://localhost:8080/v0/croissant1234` in the `updateCroissants` method. There are no `/`s in your code. Can you also share how you call this method?

Comment: @echonax : edited ;) thank you again for your help

Comment: Ok then change the line to `return this.http.put('http://localhost:8080/v0/croissant/' + ownerId + "/" + startDate  + "/" + endDate  + "/" + text)`

Comment: @echonax : thank you very much, i've some other problems now but i'll debug my self. Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem :-) glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateCroissants` method need to take the id parameter from place that you are calling it.

So it should look like:

```
//service
updateCroissants(id) {
        return this.http.put('http://localhost:8080/v0/croissants/' + id)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(res => <any[]> res.json().data)
                    .then(data => { return data; });
}
```

And when you are calling this function:

```
//component
this.service.updateCroissants("42").then((res)=> console.log(res));
```